# Access Wordpress slider plugin option from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When using "WP Vegas" wordpress plugin (image slider) the options are set this way:

```
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay: 8500,
        backgrounds: [{
            src: 'some-image.jpg',
            fade: 1250
        }, {
            src: 'other-image.jpg',
            fade: 1250
        }, ]
    })
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to access the "backgrounds" option from a javascript function?

Comment: You should be able to get the function object's `backgrounds` property. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @isherwood     I would like to be able to know what is the length of "backgrounds" array